# How do I upgrade mongo inside docker from 4.x to 5.x?

Tags: mongodb, docker-compose

I updated mongo image in docker-compose using `mongo:latest` which appears to be 5.x

However I think the db files themselves are no longer supported. I get this error:

```
bitcoinlatte-db | 2021-07-15T01:25:43.970+0000 E  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (-31802) [1626312343:970676][1:0x7f2580306b00], connection: __log_open_verify, 925: unsupported 
WiredTiger file version: this build only supports versions up to 4, and the file is version 5: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error Raw: [1626312343:970676][1:0x7f2580306b00], connectio
n: __log_open_verify, 925: unsupported WiredTiger file version: this build only supports versions up to 4, and the file is version 5: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error
```

Comment: You cannot upgrade directly from 4.2 to 5.0.  You must first upgrade from 4.2 to 4.4 and allow burn-in.  Then upgrade to 5.0.  If you are starting at 4.0 you must first go to 4.2, then 4.4 then 5.0.  Also for each upgrade you must set the Feature Compatible Version (FCV) to the upgrade version number.